# How to have a Scrollview inside a fixed View of height "100%" React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I would like to have a Scrollview inside a fixed View, so that when I scroll the Scrollview, the rim of the View is still always there (the View is like the frame of the scrolling content). It works when I set a fixed height for the outer View (for exemple 700). But when I set his height equal "100%" or flex:1, so that the outer View can cover all the screen, it doesn't work anymore.

Do you guys have any solution for this?

Current behaviour:
[image]
[image]
Current code:

```
<Container style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Header style={{ height: 15 }} />
        <FixedView
            style={{
                borderWidth: 5,
                height: '100%',//or flex:1
            }}
        >
            <ScrollView>{content}</ScrollView>
        </FixedView>
</Container>
```

Expected behaviour:
[image]
[image]
Code to simulate the expected behaviour:

```
<Container style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Header style={{ height: 15 }} />
        <FixedView
            style={{
                borderWidth: 5,
                height: 700
            }}
        >
            <ScrollView>{content}</ScrollView>
        </FixedView>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, a dynamic height for the frame can be obtained by subtracting the header and tabbar load from the screen height. There is a situation like this, the scroll expands the object outside the view because you give it flex 1 or height 100%.